# Correlated subquery in sql from Microsoft example

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found an example saying:
This example finds the product models for which the maximum list price is more than *twice* the average for the model.

With sql codes as:

```
SELECT p1.ProductModelID
FROM Production.Product AS p1
GROUP BY p1.ProductModelID
HAVING MAX(p1.ListPrice) >= ALL
    (SELECT AVG(p2.ListPrice)
     FROM Production.Product AS p2
     WHERE p1.ProductModelID = p2.ProductModelID);
```

I have no idea how this realized. Can anyone help me? Especially where the *twice* come from?

Comment: Can you cite where you found this example?

Comment: Ok, googled it. Looks like a copy-paste error. The example [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179357.aspx) includes `2 *` which would account for "twice the average". The version [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187731.aspx) (presumably where you're looking) doesn't include the multiplication by 2, but retains the same description.

Comment: Still not sure why the `ALL` is required, since the subquery will only ever return a single value - there's no `group by` in it..

Comment: What is your question?